# Installing an APK Programmatically (Android 12)

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm attempting to install an APK programmatically on Android 12 but seem to be running into unknown issues at this point. All advice I've found regarding installing an APK programmatically seem to be deprecated.

Currently, I'm able to save my file but whenever I attempt to install it using PackageManager.PackageInstaller, it fails silently and I'm unable to find anything in the logs suggesting what the failure might've been.

Here's my package installer object.

```
object PackageInstaller {
    @SuppressLint("WrongConstant")
    @Throws(IOException::class)
    fun installPackage(
        context: Context,
        installSessionId: String?,
        packageName: String?,
        apkStream: InputStream?
    ) {
        val packageManger = context.packageManager
        val packageInstaller = packageManger.packageInstaller
        val params = android.content.pm.PackageInstaller.SessionParams(
            android.content.pm.PackageInstaller.SessionParams.MODE_FULL_INSTALL
        )
        params.setAppPackageName(packageName)
        var session: android.content.pm.PackageInstaller.Session? = null
        try {
            val sessionId = packageInstaller.createSession(params)
            session = packageInstaller.openSession(sessionId)
            val out = session.openWrite(installSessionId!!, 0, -1)
            val buffer = ByteArray(1024)
            var length: Int
            var count = 0
            if (apkStream != null) {
                while (apkStream.read(buffer).also { length = it } != -1) {
                    out.write(buffer, 0, length)
                    count += length
                }
            }
            session.fsync(out)
            out.close()
            val intent = Intent
            intent.addFlags(Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED)
            Log.v("installer", "Installing..?")
            session.commit(
                PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                    context, sessionId,
                    intent, if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                        PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE or PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
                    } else {
                        PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
                    }

                ).intentSender
            )
        }finally {
            session?.close()
        }
    }
}
```

At this point I'm pretty lost as to where to look next. Does anyone even know if this is still possible? Or a solution to this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this it is working with android 12

```
class DownloadApk(private var context: WeakReference<Context>) {

@JvmOverloads
fun startDownloadingApk(url: String, fileName: String = "App Update") {
    if (URLUtil.isValidUrl(url)) {
        DownloadNewVersion(context, url, fileName).execute()
    }
}

@Suppress("DEPRECATION")
private class DownloadNewVersion(
    private val context: WeakReference<Context>,
    val downloadUrl: String,
    val fileName: String
) : AsyncTask<String, Int, Boolean>() {

    private lateinit var bar: ProgressDialog

    override fun onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute()
        bar = ProgressDialog(context.get()).apply {
            setCancelable(false)
            setMessage("Downloading...")
            isIndeterminate = true
            setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false)
            show()
        }
    }

    override fun onProgressUpdate(vararg values: Int?) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(*values)
        var msg = ""
        val progress = values[0]
        if (progress != null) {
            bar.progress = progress
            msg = if (progress > 99) "Finishing... " else "Downloading... $progress%"
        }

        bar.apply {
            isIndeterminate = false
            max = 100
            setMessage(msg)
        }
    }

    override fun onPostExecute(result: Boolean?) {
        super.onPostExecute(result)
        bar.dismiss()
        if (result != null && result) {
            context.get()?.let {
                Toast.makeText(it, "Update Done", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }

        } else {
            context.get()?.let {
                Toast.makeText(it, "Error: Try Again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }

        }
    }

    override fun doInBackground(vararg p0: String?): Boolean {
        var flag = false

        try {
            val path =
                Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)
                    .toString() + "/"
            var outputFile = File("$path$fileName.apk")
            var repetition = 1
            while (outputFile.exists()) {
                outputFile = File("$path$fileName ($repetition).apk")
                repetition++
            }

            val directory = File(path)
            if (!directory.exists()) {
                directory.mkdirs()
            }

            val url = URL(downloadUrl)
            val c = url.openConnection() as HttpURLConnection
            c.requestMethod = "GET"
            c.connect()

            val fos = FileOutputStream(outputFile)
            val inputStream = c.inputStream
            val totalSize = c.contentLength.toFloat() //size of apk

            val buffer = ByteArray(1024)
            var len1: Int
            var per: Float
            var downloaded = 0f
            while (inputStream.read(buffer).also { len1 = it } != -1) {
                fos.write(buffer, 0, len1)
                downloaded += len1
                per = (downloaded * 100 / totalSize)
                publishProgress(per.toInt())
            }
            fos.close()
            inputStream.close()
            openNewVersion(outputFile.path)
            flag = true
        } catch (e: MalformedURLException) {
            Log.e("DownloadApk", "Update Error: " + e.message)
            flag = false
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }

        return flag
    }

    private fun openNewVersion(location: String) {
        val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
        intent.setDataAndType(
            getUriFromFile(location),
            "application/vnd.android.package-archive"
        )
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
        context.get()?.startActivity(intent)
    }

    private fun getUriFromFile(filePath: String): Uri? {
        return if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
            Uri.fromFile(File(filePath))
        } else {
            context.get()?.let {
                FileProvider.getUriForFile(
                    it,
                    it.packageName + ".provider",
                    File(filePath)
                )    
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I had been stuck at this PackageInstaller thing too.

I can point out two things:

- You assign `Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED` to the intent that is to be delivered via PendingIntent, but that intent will be added `PackageInstaller.EXTRA_STATUS` with `PackageInstaller.STATUS_PENDING_USER_ACTION`, which has to be handled almost certainly by yourself (to post a new intent via `Intent.EXTRA_INTENT` extra field). Any system receiver that receives `Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED` will not post it automatically (unless you have soem code that handles it).
- You'd have to use `PendingIntent.FLAG_MUTABLE` instead of `PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE`. The intent to be dispatched will be modified by the actual installer service (assigning extra fields). If the intent is immutable, then the attempt to modify the intent will fail and your broadcast receiver will receive nothing.

Here is a [link to my working code](https://github.com/atsushieno/android-ci-package-installer/blob/2aca247c9d556ede41fb9420bd64699af3ff8a6c/cipackageinstaller/src/main/java/dev/atsushieno/cipackageinstaller/AppModel.kt#L116) that resolved these issues.